# Visa refusal and reapplication

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I was refused a UK visa application  in January 2010 which the eco stated that I have not established myself independently here in my country, then I reapplied again in June 2022,I was refused again and the eco stated that I have indicated that am single and self employed as managing director of my company and supporting documents submitted including my personal bank statement and certificate of incorporation and further stated that after CAC public search my company was currently inactive. This happened at the time of their search but currently it's active. And my application form clearly stated that am married not single, I have a copy with me. Please advice me on what to do thank you
George.

Comment: Did you provide a copy of your marriage certificate? A company with only a few months of activity isn’t going to convince an ECO of much. All you can realistically do is wait until your business can show a longer period of financial stability and profitability, including tax returns

Comment: Yes I provided my marriage certificate and my finance is stable but i want to know if it's wrong to use my personal account as a business person.

Comment: Using your personal account for business purposes means that an ECO cannot readily distinguish between transactions relating to the business and personal transactions. It makes it unclear whether any money in the account belongs to the business or to you. If you want to reapply, run your accounts separately for at least 6 months.